# Why would the beast eat that way?

Tags: beauty-and-the-beast-2017

In *Beauty and the Beast (2017)* movie, the beast was seen eating (possibly) soup directly with mouth. Seeing this, Belle even dropped her own spoon and started drinking directly from plate.

In the movie, when Belle was surprised to see that the Beast knew Shakespeare, he replied that he had an expensive education and then he took her to his personal library. It means that only appearance of the prince was changed by the curse. His mind remained intact.

How could the beast, a former prince, forget his table manners? He could have easily used a spoon or goblet as he had human type fingers.

Comment: Maybe with his physiology it made more sense to eat as he did.

Comment: Because he's become... wait for it.... bestial!

Comment: “when Belle was surprised to see that the Beast knew Shakespeare, he replied that he had an expensive education and then he took her to his personal library. It means that only appearance of the prince was changed by the curse. His mind remained intact.” It proves that! Beyond a shadow of a doubt! The library thing conclusively shows that his mind had not been changed in any way! This, as we all know, is exactly how brains work!

Comment: Because he did it that way in the original

Comment: I agree with @PaulDWaite on this.  Less snarkily, the fact that he has been educated and hasn't gotten rid of his library does not mean he hasn't started taking on some bestial aspects.  I haven't seen the live action version, but the animated version showed him at least going to growls and snarls, and fighting wolves more like an animal than a man.  If the live action is the same then clearly there have been *some* changes to his self image at least.  Plus, I drink soup from the bowl all the time without the excuse of a curse...

Comment: Maybe he ate that way before he became a Beast. You don't know.

Comment: Beast or not, if there's no one around, I'd turn into a massive shlob as well. Like, the only reason I wear clothes or eat using utensils rather than just plow my face into a steak is because it's frowned upon in society.

Comment: @Paul: You didn't miss anything.  The live action version is basically identical to the animated version, except in live action.  (The internet claims that there is a very brief allusion to Lefou being gay which was not present in the original, but it was so brief that I missed it entirely despite knowing to look for it!)

Comment: @Kevin I missed it too, but Russia found it big enough to give the movie a 16+ rating

Answer (score 1):

> In the movie, when Belle was surprised to see that the Beast knew Shakespeare, he replied that he had an expensive education and then he took her to his personal library. It means that only appearance of the prince was changed by the curse. His mind remained intact.

Actually, I think that's a bit of a stretch, for several reasons.

Firstly, and most importantly, **etiquette is not the same as learnedness.**  You can know Shakespeare and be an uncultured jerk, or you can be really polite but uneducated.  The Beast knowing Shakespeare and the Beast *not* knowing table manners are not inconsistent with each other.  He was a prince, but he was also the most important person for miles around.  If he ate "improperly," nobody would have said a word.

Secondly, he spent several years in isolation between his transformation and the main events of the film.  Anyone separated from society for that long is likely to stop caring about social graces, regardless of what an enchantress may or may not have done to them.  On the other hand, while you can certainly stop caring about Shakespeare, and while you can certainly forget most of the details of Shakespeare, it is far harder to stop knowing Shakespeare entirely.

Thirdly, and perhaps a bit less directly relevant, the out-of-universe reason Belle was surprised is because the audience is supposed to be surprised.  This scene is a clear deviation from the animated film, in which the Beast struggled to read at all (but nonetheless owned lots of books which he presumably *used to* be able to read).  Considering the overall scope of the plot changes, it seems likely this was done in order to accelerate some of the plot threads (the Beast turning "civilized" faster) and make room for Belle's parents and backstory, as well as a couple of other subplots such as Maurice and Gaston going to "rescue" Belle.  *Why* they felt the need to include those elements is less immediately obvious to me, but I assume they wanted a rounder and "more complex" narrative.

Finally, we may postulate (albeit with very limited evidence*) that the enchantment did have an effect on the Beast's mannerisms and behavior, but not on his conscious thoughts or knowledge.  I'm not sure this assumption is necessary, since it would seem to make the enchantment needlessly more difficult to break, but the enchantress may have felt it justified to do so for precisely that reason.

* The specific evidence in question is his extraordinarily harsh treatment of Maurice, compared to his relatively lenient treatment of the enchantress.  Yes, Maurice technically stole a rose from the garden, which the enchantress did not, but the castle appeared quite abandoned and Maurice couldn't have known that anyone would have cared.  Life imprisonment for petty theft seems harsh by modern standards, but those are probably the wrong standards to apply because [Sacred Hospitality](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SacredHospitality) is the basis of the enchantress's snub.  Nevertheless, the intended interpretation is clearly that the Beast was being unreasonable.

Answer (score -1):

Because, just like the other people in the castle, he's losing his humanity, forgetting things like "how to use a spoon", etc.

If Belle hadn't gotten to him, his mind would've been completely gone

This was explained in supplemental materials

Comment: Could you reference the "supplemental materials"?

Comment: @JohnP no, because I cannot remember where I saw them